# TypeScript - extract types to a separate package?

Tags: typescript

i have a React/TypeScript app with multiple (around ~100) files in which different types are defined. I want to extract all of those types to a separate package. Is there an easy/automated way of doing this, instead of manually copy-pasting the types into the new package?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There may be an alternative solution if you can explain your end goal.

Comment: @DBS, there are client applications that now require access to the types of my application.

Comment: You'll have to change your module specifiers in order to reference the external package after you separate it anyway so not really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TypeScript compiler to generate only declaration: `tsc src/*.ts --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly`

```
--declaration - Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project

--emitDeclarationOnly - Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files.
```

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html